# How to see templates in a Community

Tags: experience-cloud, community-template

I am trying to see what templates are available in my Community.  I am looking for this because I am unable to create new custom object Community pages with the template (Digital Workspace) I purchased from 7Summits.  Salesforce tech support is indicating that I don't have the template used to setup my community.  Thy said there is a Salesforce bug that won't let new object pages be created without the original Community template in place.  I don't understand how my Community is running the template but it isn't there.  To better understand what is happening, I would like to know where I can see the templates that are in my Community. I have my code in VisualStudio.  Not sure if I should be able to see it there.

Comment: If you look at the [appexchange for Digital Highlights](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJcsgUAD), you will see it is not a Community Template but a `Lightning Bolt`. [Lightning Bolts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_export_overview.htm&type=5) can be, among other things, wrappers around Community templates. If there is a bug, you fix it in the Community you have rather than generating a new one.

Comment: I am going to share this information with Salesforce tech support.  They keep asking me for the original template.  I am not sure if they are aware that it is a Bolt.  I am concerned about this because I have been able to create new custom object pages over the 1.5 years we have used it.  Something has changed apparently with Salesforce.  Salesforce is saying it is a Salesforce bug.  I just need it fixed.  Thoughts?  I am in a big jam if I can't create more custom object pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the available templates when you create a new community:

[image]

Here the list of the templates you can choose from when creating a new commnunity:

[image]

Comment: The Digital Workspace template doesn't show there.  When I am in Builder, I can see the Digital Workspace theme associated with my current Community.  Do you know what this means?  How does a theme relate to a template?  Salesforce says I need the Digital Workspace template that my Community was created with to fix the bug that we are experiencing.